# Java FailingHttpStatusCodeException

Tags: java, api, user-interface, deprecated

I have two Java Files. One is called X and The other is called Y (I couldn't copy and paste here for length). X uses HtmlUnit to automate web browsing and Y is a GUI. When I run X by itself, I get my proper output. However, when I run Y (which calls X for its functions), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 500 Internal Server Error for http://www.hmdb.ca/spectra/ms/search
```

I have tried this but error does not go away :

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why X works by itself but when run with a GUI, it gives me this run-time error? Also, when I compile Y, I get the following message:

```
Note: MetaboFrontEnd.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 500 means that your server crashes based on the request you have sent. No idea why.

To nail down the problem you can enable HttpClient wire logging or use a proxy like Charles to get all the details sent over the wire. Then you can compare the logs (with/without) ui and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 500 means that your server crashes based on the request you have sent.

In my case, jenkins error was throwed by **org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase** and the error was that I was using an environment variable to create the url so in test environment this variable was null.

Solution was use a string var instead of environment var just for test.

This was my stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 13.683 s <<< FAILURE! - in InjectedTest
[ERROR] org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyTestSuite(org.jvnet.hudson.test.junit.FailedTest)  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< ERROR!
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 500 Server Error for http://localhost:43639/closures/?uuid=166d1087-2718-4106-960c-1a4fb90bda64
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:535)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:360)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase$WebClient.goTo(HudsonTestCase.java:1602)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase$WebClient.goTo(HudsonTestCase.java:1590)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase$WebClient.executeOnServer(HudsonTestCase.java:1510)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.executeOnServer(HudsonTestCase.java:1360)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyTestSuite.runGroupedTests(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:157)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.junit.GroupedTest.run(GroupedTest.java:51)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
```